# Post Method Error : "The request timed out." - Swift

Tags: swift

I am sending data to api using the post method. But while working in advance, I have now moved my server to the windows sdd server and started to get the problem I wrote below all the time. While working on Similator, it doesn't work when I try it on my physical phone, I get this problem. What is the problem? A situation related to the firewall? Because I started to get this problem after moving the server. Or another problem?

> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=....php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=....php,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

```
  @objc func veriGonder() {
         let url = NSURL(string: "...php")
         var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
         request.httpMethod = "POST"
...
                            dataString = dataString + "&formCLASSNAMESTARIH\(verıTURUSTarih)"
                            dataString = dataString + "&formCLASSNAMESZAMAN\(verıTURUsZaman)"
...
  let dataD = dataString.data(using: .utf8) 
          do {

  let uploadJob = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD)
                                                   {
                                                       data, response, error in
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to send this request through postman or some other testing service.

Comment: Yes i tried it, it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here as the error specifies your request timed out. So to fix this either you need to increase the timeout interval or increase the server response interval from server-side. So, if it's the first option here's the code you need:

```
request.timeoutInterval = 100 // increase this to your desired value.
```